# Extra explications for the iPhone activation purpose

Tags: iphone, ios

Can somebody help me with some extra explications about iPhone activation? I had read this [article](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Activation) and understood that this activation allows the end-user to access the home screen of the smartphone with all its apps. But I don't understand what is happening behind the scene of an activation. What information is the smartphone sending to the Apple servers? And what is the smartphone expecting to receive back from these servers?

Also, I will write bellow all my questions to have some order in the ideas.

1) Can I bypass this activation to use the smartphone? ( Something similar to Samsung bypass. I don't know, I am trying to make some analogy )

2) If I don't activate the iPhone can I install a custom OS? ( in the Android world I can install a custom OS from Cyanogenmod )

3) Why doesn't Android devices have this activation step?

4) If I don't activate the iPhone, can I jailbreak it?

5) When would the activation fail, and not because of the bad internet connection?

6) Can I, us a developer/hacker do anything with the iPhone if I am not activating it by executing any [terminal commands](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice) to change any settings in any way. And after the activation, the changes done by me to be reset to default?

7) Can I set my iCloud account if the iPhone is not activated?

To don't understand me wrong, I understand that when I am buying an Apple smartphone from the local store, my friend or whoever is selling it. I am paying for the hardware and the software, and this is one of the reasons for these devices to be expensive. But why, should I (the end-user) bother to activate this phone when I know, that the software is bound to the hardware?

Thanks in advanced
[image]

Comment: Your question is rather broad and at least partially already answered in a previous question (see link on top) and in the article you reference. If necessary please ask new questions for a specific unclear point separately

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to give me an answer, and I know that I am stupid, but I still don't have an answer to any of my 7 questions. If I don't activate the iPhone, is it possible to do any of the 7 things mentions in my 7 questions?

Comment: These seven items are way too broad, there are lot of possible answers which only will address part of these items. Can you focus on one first, ask a specific question about this and then ask additional questions separately? This will make it easier to provide specific answers and/or point you to existing information.